# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory , even i have image in the folder

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load all the images before i can head towards my CNN model but i am getting this error.I don't know what is the problem. please help me out.

```
# Setting up the image pool
image_path = "C:\\Users\\New\\Desktop\\images"
imgs = os.listdir(image_path)
img_x = img_y = 50 # image size is constant
n_samples = np.size(imgs)
n_samples # 20778 originally

# Loading all images...
images = np.array([np.array(Image.open(image_path +  
imgs).convert("RGB")).flatten() for imgs in os.listdir(image_path)], 
order='F', dtype='uint8')
np.shape(images)
```

i got this error

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 # Loading all images...
----> 2 images = np.array([np.array(Image.open(image_path + imgs).convert("RGB")).flatten() for imgs in os.listdir(image_path)], order='F', dtype='uint8')
      3 np.shape(images)

in (.0)
      1 # Loading all images...
----> 2 images = np.array([np.array(Image.open(image_path + imgs).convert("RGB")).flatten() for imgs in os.listdir(image_path)], order='F', dtype='uint8')
      3 np.shape(images)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2607 
   2608     if filename:
-> 2609         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2610         exclusive_fp = True
   2611

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\New\Desktop\imagesAlfa Romeo10882_small.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you used image_path + imgs, lets assuem in imgs you have the one image relative path, it will be still missing a "/" try please to use `os.path.join` to avoid it.
2. when you run the for loop it is redundant to run over `os.listdir(image_path)` as you already have it under imgs,

try the following, should work

```
from PIL import Image
image_path = "path to folder with images...."
imgs = os.listdir(image_path) # create a list of all the files inside the fodler
img_x = img_y = 50  # image size is constant
n_samples = np.size(imgs)
print(n_samples) 

images = np.array([np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(image_path,im)).convert("RGB")).flatten() for im in imgs],
                      order='F', dtype='uint8')
print(np.shape(images))
```

my output is :

```
1000
(1000, 921600)
```

good luck